# Read a file name from a text file then search the hard drive for it using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am just beginning to write my own batch scripts and currently I am trying to develop a small batch script to read a text file containing a list of specific file names with extensions one at a time.  After reading the file name, search the hard drive for that file and if found, move it to a specific directory.

This is the code I have developed thus far.  It works as long as the files you are looking for are in the same directory.  The OS I am using is Windows 8.1.

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
for /F "delims=" %%a in (VIRUS_LIST.txt) do (
echo searching for %%a
echo.    
For /R %%G in (%%a) do (
if exist %%a (
copy "%%G" "c:\vault"
echo moving file at %%G to c:\vault
echo.
)
)
)
pause
```

Here is how I would like it to work; 1. read the file name from the VIRUS_LIST.TXT file, 2. scan drive C for that file, 3. If found copy or move it to a directory on C drive called C:\vault.

The list file I am using is called VIRUS_LIST.TXT that holds the file names to search for, and if found they would be moved to C:\VAULT to be processed later.  If anyone can offer any help it would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: "*If anyone can offer any help it would be greatly welcomed.*" - drop batch, use PowerShell. `$Names = get-content VIRUS_LIST.txt; Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse | Where Name -in $Names | Move-Item -Destination C:\Vault`

Comment: Your approach is a bit naive. The `for /r` needs a folder to start with `for /r c:\ ` The `ìf exist %%a`is superfluous and as `%%a` is unquoted will break the batch encountering a path/name containing spaces.

Comment: First let me thank you TessellatingHeckler for your input and PowerShell script.  I do intend on learning PowerShell, but wanted to learn Batch Scripting 1st as it seemed a bit stupid not to start from the ground up.  A good footing in Batch would aid me in learning other languages later as it requires no compiler to "see" what is going on.    Next thank you LotPings, your suggestions did help but made me understand that in order for this script to run correctly, I had to install it and the search file VIRUS_LIST.txt in the root directory of C drive. It does work correctly from there.  Thank u